# Flask Session Cookie Expiration

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, session-cookies

I am trying to set the expiration for a cookie to be longer than the browser session. My `config.py` is:

```
from datetime import timedelta
SESSION_FILE_DIR = 'C:/some/path15'
SECRET_KEY= 'abcdefg'
DEBUG = True
SESSION_PERMANENT = True
PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME = timedelta(days=30)
```

And then to mimic my app structure for this example, I have the main app which registers a blueprint:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session, current_app
from flask_session import Session
import tempfile
 
server = Flask(__name__)
server.config.from_pyfile('config.py')

### Import and Register Blueprints 
from tools.routes import my_bp

server.register_blueprint(my_bp)

@server.route('/')
def homepage():
    return "Hello"
   
if __name__ == '__main__':
    server.run(debug=True)
```

And then a blueprint called `routes.py` living in a subdirectory of the main app called `tools`

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session, Blueprint, current_app
from flask_session import Session
import tempfile

my_bp = Blueprint("my_bp", __name__)

@my_bp.route('/new', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def path(): 
    if 'path' not in session: ##new
        session['path'] = tempfile.mkdtemp() ##new
    path = session['path'] ##new
    return path
```

When running this app (head over the /new route), if I Inspect Element under Storage in the browser, it shows that the cookies expire/max_age is `Session`.

How can I get this to respect the 30-day expiration I have set in the `config.py` file?

Answer (score 1):

```
from flask import session, app
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    session.permanent = True
    app.permanent_session_lifetime = datetime.timedelta(minutes=20) # session will be alive for 20 minutes
```

Comment: while this answer might be correct it would be good to explain the code and add some more text to it.

Comment: Thank you, @Mangisto. In fact, I did this exact thing and it does indeed work. I would *think* setting up the configuration should work too. So, while this does indeed work, I am at the same time curious why setting this up in the ``config.py`` does not work.